# Method Calls on BlazeDS using Java

Tags: java, apache-flex, concurrency, remoting, blazeds

I have an application that makes to remote method calls to a BlaseDS server that uses Java to connect to a 3rd party data system. It needs to make 2 remote method calls `method_A()` and `method_B()`.

java `method_A()` is called on a timer of 5 seconds.

java `method_B()` is called by a user initiated action.

If the timer is complete and the Application calls `method_A()` and before `method_A()` is able to return any data `method_B()` is called, this causes `method_A()` from returning any data. Then `method_B()` throws an error.

any more calls to `method_A()` will work fine after the error is thrown but `method_B()` will not work after the error.

is there any way you can configure BlazeDS to ensure that `method_A()` finishes before `method_B()` is actioned or if `method_A()` and `method_B()` and be called concurrently with out any error? or should I refactor the service to conform to the command pattern?

Thank you in advance for any help that you may be able to provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such concurrency feature included.
The only concurrency feature is the "concurrency" variable, that affects only calls on the same method

So as you think, a solution would be to use the command pattern